# ROS2 Python Migration Guide

Tags: ros, python, ros2, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a ROS2 Python Migration Guide? My initial web searches  only found [this page](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Python-Programming) which seems old and doesn't really say how to migrate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306067/ros2-python-migration-guide/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2018-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-17**:
Isn't the info part of the general [Migration guide](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Migration-Guide)?

Hm, that's rather barren when it comes to Python actually. nm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately I don't think there's anything other than the examples to compare against ROS 1 to see the differences.

There's this in the migration guide about using just a `setup.py` in your python package (rather than CMake):

https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Migration-Guide#pure-python-package

But that's all I'm aware of.

Here's some of the examples:

- https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/master/rclpy
- https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/demo_nodes_py

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1